# Trying to use an environment variable in a .cmd script, getting the message "\Windows was unexpected at this time"

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, environment-variables

I need to access a windows environment variable in a .cmd script, it looks something like this, following the documentation on [microsoft's support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/121170/how-to-access-environment-variables-in-an-ms-dos-batch-file):

```
if "%MY_ENV_VAR%" == "" (
  echo You must set your MY_ENV_VAR environment variable.
  goto end
)

set DO_STUFF="%MY_ENV_VAR%\some_folder\doStuff.exe"
```

However, the script won't work and I am getting the following message:

> \Windows was expected at this time

Did I do something wrong? How to fix this?

I don't know how important this is, but the environment variable contains the following path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0`

Comment: You might want to try double percent signs '"%%MY_ENV_VAR%%"'

Comment: @BillHileman Unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: Does the error message point to a specific line in the script?  Does the command prompt stay open?  Can you see each line executing?

Comment: It doesn't say the specific line in which it fails. It stops executing on the if and I had to make a trail of echos to discover that. The command prompt does stay open and all it displays to me is `\Windows was unexpected at this time`

Comment: You need to escape the `)` in your variable if you are going to use this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be mixing batch language with a more advanced scripting language.  The link you show is for batch files.  To the best of my knowledge you can't write batch files like you can java code (using braces, etc.)

Here's some pseudo code that might give you an idea of how to apply the example you link to:

```
if "%MY_ENV_VAR%"=="" goto ERROR
set DO_STUFF=%MY_ENV_VAR%\some_folder\doStuff.exe
...
goto DONE
:ERROR
echo You must set your MY_ENV_VAR environment variable.
:DONE
```

It's been a while since I've written a batch file, but I think that's basically it.

Comment: " To the best of my knowledge you can't write batch files like you can java code (using braces, etc.)" Huh? Of course you can use brackets. See https://ss64.com/nt/if.html and https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html.

Comment: This is why I used the TTBOMK disclaimer, @DavidPostill.  I've been using command prompts since CP/M days but obviously I know things evolve.  I don't use batch files mutch anymore, nor do I claim to be an expert, but I thought I might be able to help. When I'm not sure, I usually make that point clear.  That's a major addition to the batch language, makes it more like a regular programming language.  I was already amazed at how complex the FOR command had become.

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. this seems to work ok for me.

But if the first IF is the problem, you could try the following instead:

```
if not defined MY_ENV_VAR (
    echo You must set your MY_ENV_VAR environment variable.
    goto end
)
```

Comment: I actually do have some progress with this. However, it works only as follows: `if not defined %KITPATH%` and it will always go into the if even if KITPATH is defined. I made sure to log it right before the if (`echo KITPATH`). Any idea what that could be?

Comment: For IF DEFINED leave out the % signs i.e. IF NOT DEFINED KITPATH. otherwise the variable will be expanded BEFORE the if test, you don't want that. You want to know if that variable is defined.